# Merge selected DataGrid Cells

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a requirement, where the user has the ability to select multiple cells (row wise or column Wise). As soon as the selection is complete I need to merge only the selected cells(not the entire row or column). I did some research online, many suggested grouping. But when I use grouping entire row is getting merged. 
Can you guys please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

DataGrids are not spreadsheets, you should probably look for another control as doing this in a DataGrid may be near impossible.

Comment: H.B
Are there any other controls that you know in WPF where I can perform the custom merging?

Comment: @edgebrk: No, you can have content spanning rows and columns in a `Grid` but there is no control which makes that easy to use in the .NET framework. Maybe campanies like [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) or [XCeed](http://xceed.com/) have implementations (or perhaps there is even something open source, don't know).